# Do we select all features when dealing with Decision Trees?

Tags: cart

I have a dataset with 6000 instances and 68 features. I have created a simple brute force decision tree that covers all features and instances but is very slow.

Is it right to select all features or do we randomly choose some features for every run?

Comment: If any of the features are continuous and you are dichotomizing them you are effectively ignoring a good part of these features, so you could say that you are ignoring features already.  But more to your point, the process you outline probably results in more noise than signal, and low probability of validation.

Comment: @FrankHarrell All of the features are continuous. So is there a better way to reduce this noise?

Comment: I would use a statistical model that treats continuous variables as continuous.  You may need penalized maximum likelihood estimation or unsupervised data reduction before fitting the model.

Comment: I run once using variable importance enabled.  This typically allows me to grossly reduce the number of columns without impacting performance.  Also, I like the 'h2o' library, because it can be quite fast.

Answer (score -1):

It is neither correct nor incorrect to include all Features. What you want to end up with is the most parsimonious model that adequately fits the data. In some cases, this may require all Features, but more often, some subset of Features will account for the most variance. This 'feature selection' step is often employed (as Frank Harrell commented) using regularization/penalization/PCA, etc. With decision trees, I believe this is called 'pruning'. Have you considered a modeling approach other than decision trees?  Decision trees often grow into an unmanageable forest.